# Hibernate DAO setting object value as object

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection

I am trying to use Hibernate on my [project](https://github.com/ArthurGibbs/Centaurus-)  << all sources if wanted, I try to create and save an object player on startup, I get the following error:

```
START SCRIPT!
org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.util.Date centaurus.domain.User.created] by reflection for persistent property [centaurus.domain.User#created] : User{id=0, email='test', created=Wed Jun 08 13:06:53 BST 2016}
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.getForInsert(GetterFieldImpl.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValuesToInsert(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:521)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.getPropertyValuesToInsert(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:228)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getPropertyValuesToInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4701)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:669)
    at centaurus.service.player.PlayerDAOimpl.saveUser(PlayerDAOimpl.java:32)
    at centaurus.Dbmaintain.start(Dbmaintain.java:25)
    at restx.factory.Factory.start(Factory.java:846)
    at restx.RestxMainRouterFactory.build(RestxMainRouterFactory.java:450)
    at restx.RestxMainRouterFactory.newInstance(RestxMainRouterFactory.java:70)
    at restx.servlet.RestxMainRouterServlet.init(RestxMainRouterServlet.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:747)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at restx.server.JettyWebServer.start(JettyWebServer.java:109)
    at restx.server.JettyWebServer.startAndAwait(JettyWebServer.java:114)
    at centaurus.AppServer.main(AppServer.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Date field centaurus.domain.User.created to centaurus.domain.User
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:39)
    ... 40 more
2016-06-08 13:06:53,232 [main            ] [          ] INFO  restx.monitor.MetricsConfiguration - registering Metrics JVM metrics
```

I have stepped through my program and it seems to have a valid object passed the the hibernate save function, and somewhere inside it throws an error. I have tried removing the created field, at which point it then complains about a string field with the same error, trying to set it as a Player object itself.

here is my DAOimpl.class

```
package centaurus.dao.user;

import centaurus.domain.User;

import centaurus.service.HibernateUtils;
import restx.factory.Component;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import javax.inject.Named;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class UserDAOimpl implements UserDAO {
    private static HibernateUtils hibernateUtils;

    public UserDAOimpl(@Named("HibernateUtils") HibernateUtils hibernateUtils) {
        this.hibernateUtils = hibernateUtils;
    }

    public User saveUser(User user){
        Session session = hibernateUtils.getFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        Integer playerID = null;
        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            //playerID = (Integer) session.save(user);
            session.save(user);

            tx.commit();

        }catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return user;
    }

    public User getUser(int playerId){
        Session session = hibernateUtils.getFactory().openSession();
        try{
            User user = (User)session.get(User.class, playerId);
            return user;
        }catch (HibernateException e) {

        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers(){
        Session session = hibernateUtils.getFactory().openSession();
        List<User> list = null;
        try{
            list = session.createCriteria(User.class).list();

        }catch (HibernateException e) {

        }finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

I have googled and googled and tried as many hibernate tutorials as i can find and I still have this issue. I don't understand why hibernate is trying to set a field as an object, I have my annotations.

incase its wanted here is my domain object player:

```
package centaurus.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private int id = 0;

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email = "";

    @Column(name="CREATED")
    private Date created = null;

    public User(){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        this.created = cal.getTime();
    };

    public User(int id, String email, Date created) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.created = created;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", created=" + created +
                '}';
    }
}
```

and here is the calling class:

```
package centaurus;

import centaurus.dao.user.UserDAO;
import centaurus.domain.User;
import restx.factory.AutoStartable;
import restx.factory.Component;

import javax.inject.Named;


@Component
public class DBMaintain implements AutoStartable{
    private UserDAO userDAO;

    public DBMaintain(@Named("UserDAOimpl") UserDAO userDAO) {
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    public void start(){
        System.out.println("START SCRIPT!");

        //test
        User p = new User();
        p.setEmail("test");
        userDAO.saveUser(p);

    }
}
```

Please does anyone know how to solve this issue, thanks.

EDIT: (added sql)

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
    USER_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    CREATED TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    EMAIL varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (USER_ID)
);
```

EDIT added hibernate config
/src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection properties - Driver, URL, user, password -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/andromeda</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">api</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">apipassword</property>
        <!-- Connection Pool Size -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured! -->
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Outputs the SQL queries, should be disabled in Production -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Dialect is required to let Hibernate know the Database Type, MySQL, Oracle etc
            Hibernate 4 automatically figure out Dialect from Database Connection Metadata -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>


        <mapping class="centaurus.domain.User"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: googled so many pages looking for a solution to this, maybe not using right keywords.

Comment: I'm almost sure here's your problem: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Date field centaurus.domain.User.created to centaurus.domain.User
`. Trying to figure out where exactly is that happening

Comment: Can you add the `CREATE TABLE` for the `users` table?

Comment: changing .save to .saveorUpdate shifts the same error to the id field. same issue though. probably just because its getting the properties in a different order.

Comment: Worked fine for me with HSQLDB and Hibernate 5.0.9.Final.

Comment: Mark, I have added the hibernate config file, i don't really understand reflection of what security manager i would be looking for. google showed how i can disallow classes from reflection access but i don't have any like that in my codebase.

Comment: Why do you have a ';' at the end of the User Constructor with the Calendar  object?

Comment: not sure,, removed but does not affect anything,

Comment: try to add '@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)' annotation to your date column

Comment: another tip, I would remove the static keyword on HibernateUtils in your DAO. Seems like rather dangerous thing to do, every instance of your DAO replaces these utils for every other instance. Maybe it is just code cleanup

Comment: @Arthur can you see if my answer resolves your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the User class from the package centaurus

why?

On AppServer.main you have:

> System.setProperty("restx.app.package", "centaurus");

this will make the restx recompile everything that's inside centaurus package and use this recompiled class, but apparently hibernate is retrieving the fields from the original class, not from the recompiled one

Here is the stacktrace that really matters:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Date field centaurus.domain.User.created to centaurus.domain.User
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:379)
```

The JVM is throwing an Exception because it cannot use the Field (that was retrieved by hibernate from the original compilation) at the class User (that was loaded by restx from the restx compilation)

Comment: Thanks for this!, Massive Help I had been stuck on that for a while. I would have rather kept by domain objects inside the package as i then get restx api benefits, but i can have separate domain and response objects.

Comment: Does this mean that hibernate and dynamic reloading of classes for development is incompatible, or should I remove "System.setProperty("restx.app.package", "centaurus");" which I assume will break the reloading. so far moving my domain class to testdomain.User seems to have worked but it seems wrong to have to have some classes outside of my package.  thanks

Comment: if you move everything that is related to restx to the package centaurus.restx and the other classes to centaurus.otherpackage and change "System.setProperty("restx.app.package", "centaurus.restx");" maybe it will work

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the answer but we will see!

Try replacing

```
CREATED TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

with

```
CREATED DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_DATETIME,
```

See the difference between Timestamp and Datetime in SQL is *TIMESTAMP values are converted from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and converted back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This occurs only for the TIMESTAMP data type, not for other types such as DATETIME.)
If you store a TIMESTAMP value, and then change the time zone and retrieve the value, the retrieved value is different from the value you stored.*
[TimeStamp MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

While *DATETIME represents a date (as found in a calendar) and a time (as can be observed on a wall clock),*

Since you cannot store Java Date into a SQL TIMESTAMP object, either change the SQL TIMESTAMP to DATETIME or change the

```
private Date created;
```

to

```
private Timestamp created;

//And convert your Date to TimeStamp
public User(){
    Date date = new Date();
    created = new Timestamp(date .getTime());
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This has not solved or changed the issue but since i wanted Datetime anyway, I give you a upvote and thanks.

Comment: @Arthur So you still have the same error or is it a different one?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate cannot transform to joda DateTime out of the box. Try to annotate your column with

```
@Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
```

See [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/userguide.html) for reference.

Comment: This is not the error seen here, even when the type is changed to Date or String the same error appears.

Comment: Which type has `created` in the database?

Comment: it is of type datetime, CREATED datetime DEFAULT now(),

Comment: Is `NULL` allowed? Which hibernate version are you using?

Comment: org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.0.Final

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a bug in this version of Hibernate

[HHH-10618](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10618)

Try to use another one.

Comment: for hibernate-core I was using 5.1.0.Final, I swapped to 5.2.0.Final(the latest on maven) and it made no difference, should i be using an older one?

Comment: In the ticket I've mentioned it is said that fix version is 5.1.1 so you could try it. Another variant is to use earlier version. It was mentioned that you example was working with 5.0.9.

Answer (score 0):

Your date field has to be annotated as follows:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "creation", updatable = false, length = 19)
public Date getCreation() {
    return this.creation;
}

public void setCreation(Date creation) {
    this.creation = creation;
}
```

Be sure to rename column and name of the filed to match your project.